# Issue when trying to create View using WITH

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create the following view, the query runs find until I try to create a View and then I get an error which states: Create View or Function failed because no column name was specified for column 1, research I've found hasn't really helped as it's usually something simple wrong with the query but mine runs fine on its own currently. Any insight?

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.prov_prod_rv AS

WITH rep_prods AS (SELECT t.amount, t.provider_id, t.clinic, p.period_start, t.impacts, 
p.period_end, p.period_id, p.fiscal_year, p.date_man
FROM dbo.transactions AS t 
CROSS JOIN dbo.period AS p
WHERE (t.date_entered BETWEEN p.period_start AND p.period_end))

SELECT SUM(r.amount), r.provider_id, d.first_name, d.last_name, d.position_id, d.clinic, r.period_id, r.fiscal_year, r.date_man
FROM rep_prods AS r INNER JOIN
dbo.provider AS d ON r.provider_id = d.provider_id AND r.clinic = d.clinic
WHERE (r.impacts = 'P') AND (r.amount <> 0)
GROUP BY r.provider_id, d.first_name, d.last_name, d.position_id, d.clinic, r.period_id, r.fiscal_year, r.date_man
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in your final `SELECT`:

```
SELECT   SUM(r.amount), 
         r.provider_id, 
         d.first_name, 
         d.last_name, 
         d.position_id, 
         d.clinic, 
         r.period_id, 
         r.fiscal_year, 
         r.date_man
```

You need to give a column name to the `SUM(r.amount)` column:

```
SELECT   SUM(r.amount) As TotalAmount, 
         r.provider_id, 
         d.first_name, 
         d.last_name, 
         d.position_id, 
         d.clinic, 
         r.period_id, 
         r.fiscal_year, 
         r.date_man
```

Comment: Awesome, that did the trick. I missed that, thanks for the quick answer

Comment: @OMAsphyxiate Errors are easier to find where the query is formatted ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Column 1 is `SUM(r.amount)`. It has no name (or alias). Just running this as a query isn't a problem because SSMS doesn't need a column name, but in a view the view must have a column name. Give it an alias such as `SUM(r.amount) AS TotalAmount`